# Fragment save state on configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-configchanges

I am developing twitter client.
I have TimelineFragment with loaders which load data from db and web.
I have setRetainInstance(true) in onActivityCreated.

When orientation change view recycled? how i can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to save. Your member variables will be saved but you will have to use them to reinitialize your view widgets such as TextView, EditText, Buttons.

Alternatively if its simple data you want to save such as text on TextViews, EditText, Buttons, etc.., you can use an xml feature on them called "freezesText"

Comment: Can you post some code so that we can see how you are loading data with a loader ?

Comment: onActivityCreated init loader and loader get from db timeline.